# Collision function not working yet movement is inhibited. No other movement inhibiting code.

Tags: javascript, html

```
var rightPressed = false;
var leftPressed = false;
var upPressed = false;
var downPressed = false;


var players = [];
players[0] = new victim(1234);


var arrayw = 50;
var arrayh = 50;
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle="#736AFF";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,600,600);

var arenaarray = new Array(50);
for(var z = 0; z < 50; z++) {
    arenaarray[z] = new Array(50);
}
for(var q = 0; q < 50; q++) {
    for(var r = 0; r < 50; r++) {
        arenaarray[q][r] = 0;
    }
}

// draws top border
for(var z = 0; z < 50; z++) {
    arenaarray[z][0] = 1;
}
// draws right border
for(var z = 0; z < 50; z++) {
    arenaarray[49][z] = 1;
}
// draws bottom border
for(var z = 0; z < 50; z++) {
    arenaarray[z][49] = 1;
}
// draws left border
for(var z = 0; z < 50; z++) {
    arenaarray[0][z] = 1;
}

// random line
for(var m = 10; m < 30; m++) {
    arenaarray[m][10] = 1;
}




function victim(ID){
    this.ID = ID;
    this.health = 100;
    this.speed = 100;
    this.direction = 0;
// this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    // this.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 500);
    this.x = 200;
    this.y = 200;
}


// deals with keybaord inputs
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);

function keyDownHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        rightPressed = true;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
        leftPressed = true;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 38) {
        upPressed = true;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 40) {
        downPressed = true;
    }
}
function keyUpHandler(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 39) {
        rightPressed = false;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 37) {
        leftPressed = false;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 38) {
        upPressed = false;
    }
    else if(e.keyCode == 40) {
        downPressed = false;
    }
}



function paintPlayers() {
    for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        // iterates through players and finds their x and y. Paints a circle.
        // also needs to remove old player locations
    }
}

// obtain keycodes
// 0 is up, 1 is right, 2 is down, 3 is left
// finish coding. s
function updatePositions() {
    console.log(checkCollisions(players[0].x + 0.5, players[0].y));
    for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
        if(rightPressed == true && checkCollisions(players[0].x + 0.5, players[0].y) == false) {
            players[0].x += 2;
        }
        else if(leftPressed == true && checkCollisions(players[0].x - 0.5, players[0].y) == false) {
            players[0].x -= 2;
        }
        else if(upPressed == true && checkCollisions(players[0].x, players[0].y - 0.5) == false) {
            players[0].y -= 2;
        }
        else if(downPressed == true && checkCollisions(players[0].x, players[0].y + 0.5) == false) {
            players[0].y += 2;
        }
    } 
}

// draws the player sprite
function draw() {
    updatePositions();
    // repaints light bleu over everything to redraw
    ctx.fillStyle = "#6960F5";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,600,600);
    drawArena();
    // repaints player locations
    drawPlayers();


}

// draws the arena
function drawArena() {
    for(var m = 0; m < arrayw; m++) {
        for(var n = 0; n < arrayh; n++) {
            if(arenaarray[m][n] === 1) {
                ctx.fillStyle = "#CCCCCC";
                ctx.fillRect(m*12, n*12, 12, 12); 
            }
        }
    }


}

function drawPlayers() {
    for(var j = 0; j < players.length; j++) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        // document.getElementById("myDiv").style.top = players[j].y + "px";
        // document.getElementById("myDiv").style.left = players[j].x + "px";
        // temporary implementation. Delete everything then repaint walls

        ctx.arc(players[j].x, players[j].y, 6, 0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#00FF00";
        ctx.fill(); 
        ctx.closePath();

    }
}

// collision checker for both walls + players
// returns true if there are any collisions
```

This is the function that checks for collisions. If there is one, it returns true, which then blocks moment in the above updatePositions().

If you run this code, and look at dev tools on the html page, you will see that checkCollisions is continuously false and is never true. However, the circle (victim) is blocked from moving.

```
function checkCollisions(x,y) {
    exactx = x;
    exacty = y;
    x = Math.floor(x/12);
    y = Math.floor(y/12);
    // checks for top wall
    // areana array is the array of 1's and 0's that the map is based on
    if(arenaarray[x][y-1] === 1) {
        if(Math.floor(exacty/12) != Math.floor((exacty-6)/12)) {
            console.log("am I working1");
            return true;
        }
    }
    // checks or right wall
    else if(arenaarray[x+1][y] === 1) {
        if(Math.floor(exactx/12) != Math.floor((exactx+6)/12)) {
            console.log("am I working2");
            return true;
        }
    }
    // checks for bottom wall
    else if(arenaarray[x][y+1] === 1) {
        if(Math.floor(exacty/12) != Math.floor((exacty+6)/12)) {
            console.log("am I working3");
            return true;
        }
    }
    // checks for left wall
    else if(arenaarray[x-1][y] === 1) {
        if(Math.floor((exactx-6)/12) != Math.floor(exactx/12)) {
            console.log("am I working4");
            return true;
        }
    }

    // otherwise, check for corner intersection (because this either means its
    // not
    // intersecting or their are only walls in the corners

    // checks for top left corner
    else if(arenaarray[x-1][y-1] === 1) {
        if(distance(exactx, (x-1)*12, exacty, (y-1)*12) < victim.radius) {
            console.log("am I working5");
            return true;
        }
    }
    // checks for the top right corner
    else if(arenaarray[x+1][y-1] === 1) {
        if(distance(exactx, (x+1)*12, exacty, (y-1)*12) < victim.radius) {
            console.log("am I working6");
            return true;
        }
    }
    // checks for the bottom right corner
    else if(arenaarray[x+1][y+1] === 1) {
        if(distance(exactx, (x+1)*12, exacty, (y+1)*12) < victim.radius) {
            console.log("am I working7");
            return true;
        }
    }
    // checks for the bottom left corner
    else if(arenaarray[x-1][y+1] === 1) {
        if(distance(exactx, (x-1)*12, exacty, (y+1)*12) < victim.radius) {
            console.log("am I working8");
            return true;
        }
    }
    else {
    return false;
    }

}




// if(distance(x, x1, y, y1) || distance(x, x2, y, y2) || distance(x, x1, y, y1)
// || distance(x, x1, y, y1)) {

// }

function distance(x1, x2, y1, y2) {
    return Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));
}


// freezes for n milliseconds? Bad???
function sleep(milliseconds) {
      var start = new Date().getTime();
      for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) { 
        if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
          break;
        }f
      }
    }
// prevents scrolling
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    // space, page up, page down and arrow keys:
    if([32, 33, 34, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);

/*
 * 
 * while(counter < 100) { console.log("this is being called");
 * console.log(document.getElementById('xcood'))
 * document.getElementById('xcood').innerHTML = counter; // updatePositions(); //
 * 1. move characters // 2. check for collisions between players // 3. death
 * events counter++;
 *  }
 * 
 */
setInterval(draw, 10);
```

This is my index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#myDiv {
   position: relative;
}

#myCanvas {
    background-color: light-blue;
}

</style>

</head>

<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
<!-- <div id="myDiv" STYLE = "POSITION: absolute; TOP: 0px; LEFT: 0px" ><img src = "http://i.imgur.com/3YgFMpS.png"></div> -->
<br>
<script type="text/javascript"src="./src/gameboard.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just so you know, in `updatePositions`, you're looping through `players` but only accessing `players[0]`. It should be `players[i]`.

Comment: `checkCollisions()` has three possible return values: `true`, `false`, and `undefined`. Not sure if that's the problem (is that `console.log()` logging any `undefined` values?), but it is probably something you should fix regardless. Have you logged `rightPressed` and the other variables to check that they're set correctly?

Comment: P.S. *"freezes for n milliseconds? Bad???"* - Yes. Bad. Don't do this.

Comment: Yes it is logged undefined. the code at line 114 that has players[0]x. and players[0].y - 5

Comment: @nnnnnn It logged as undefined. I'm using parameters players[0].y - 0.5 in order to check for collisions preemptively. For example, if I plan to move up (subtracting y coordinate), I would check if there will be collisions if I check a y coordinate slightly smaller than where I am currently.

Comment: You can fix `checkCollisions()` so that it doesn't return `undefined` by removing the final `else` case and just having `return false;` as the last line of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Found issue. The nested if statements did not allow it to check further conditions. Because there was no else statement within each of the else if's, it returned undefined.